# How to dynamically cast value typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a repository that has two methods: `create` and `edit`. `Create` method receives the first argument of type `A` and `edit` receives first argument of type `B`. I have the following scenario:

```
interface A {
    foo: string;
}

interface B {
    bar: string;
}

class AddressRepository {
    public create(obj: A) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public edit(obj: B) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

let operation: 'create' | 'edit' = true ? 'create' : 'edit';
let obj: A | B = {
    foo: 'bar'
};

(new AddressRepository())[operation](obj);
```

I get the following error: `Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A & B'.
  Property 'bar' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'.`. How can I tell the compiler that the type of `obj` variable will be decided based on the value of the variable `operation`?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=43#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20TAewIC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfLLUSWRFAIUxzwCM4UUhSog6jZggA2cMmTQATBVAhyAShAAOBMsDAEoATx55kmgK58pwBMgQq4kABQE%20AK1KoAlCdN4A9P7ICgTkYOYwMLy4TNFmlta2EAp6Lu6knD7YfgFBIWERUaZMsVIQYMgEmtCOwAQgpADk9hCOEI3IAD7Ijcl6HQC8yJTmKAD8PS1tHU19YI30ZRWuHmhdyNxD2XiEJD0CUI2M9FhOIBAA7orKqmQa2rr6Rk5eXgDaVTVgdSAAumluLy0IA)

Comment: Just remove explicit typing: `let operation = true ? 'create' : 'edit';
let obj = {
    foo: 'bar'
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, you should `link` the two parameters (operation name and object). To do this, you can use multiple interfaces, where each one defines a full object with operation name and input value. This can be used as an "Union" type, where the `operation` key will act as the discriminator, letting the TS engine know which value are you using related to the operation:

```
type AInput = {
    operation: 'create',
    obj: A;
}

type BInput = {
    operation: 'edit',
    obj: B;
}

const action: AInput | BInput = { operation: 'edit', obj: { bar: 'abc' } };

(new AddressRepository())[action.operation](action.obj);
```

This will not throw error ([see in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=31&ssc=57&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+TAewIC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfLLUSWRFAIUxzwCM4UUhSog6jZggA2cMmTQATBVAhyAShAAOBMsDAEoATx55kmgK58pwBMgQq4kABQE+AK1KoAlCdN4A9P7ICgTkYOYwMLy4TNFmlta2EAp6Lu6knD7YfgFBIWERUaZMsWCGmiioAJIgFmDIALy+uAQVUI7ABCCkAOT2EI4QPQA0ca4eaPSl5Vw1dY3NyK3QHV29yXojY+nInFOSXRTIiGCd3Whz5vUAPruX9U0YS22r5z0bYCNLO08CQsg9OB8BA9ZAMMH0LBOEAQADuimUqjIGm0un0RicXi8AG0TmcAHTLdqnLoAXSceK6hPcXloQA)) since TS now knows that `action.obj` is strictly related to `action.operation`.

Furthermore, you can extract automatically (if you'd like to) these types directly from the class, like this:

```
type AddressRepositoryInput = {
    [K in keyof AddressRepository]: AddressRepository[K] extends (obj: infer TObj) => infer R
    ? { type: K, obj: TObj }
    : never;
}[keyof AddressRepository];
```

then you can just type:

```
const action: AddressRepositoryInput = { type: 'edit', obj: { ... } };
```

and it will validate your input.